# Is the multiset of prime gaps in an admissible $ k $ -tuple of minimal diameter $ d $ determined by $ (k,d) $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let  $ (p,p+g_{1},p+g_{1}+g_{2},...,p+g_{1}+g_{2}+\cdots g_{k}) $ a prime constellation. Can the multiset  $ \{g_{i}\} $ be recovered by the knowledge of the sum of its elements and its cardinal ?

Comment: Generally speaking, no. Consider for example $11,13,17,19$ and $101,103,107, 109$.

Comment: Well, in both sequences the (multi)set of prime gaps is  $ \{2,4,2\} $.